# Return a value using a JS function in onsubmit form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JS function that returns the value of my input, I want to use it to put this value in the link sent by **onsubmit form**.

here is my code:

```js
function getValue() {
  return 'videoYoutube.asp?lienYout=' + document.getElementById("lienYoutube").value;
}

function setFormUrl() {
  var url = getValue();
  document.getElementById('testForm').setAttribute('action', url);
}
```

```html
<form id="testForm" method="get" onsubmit="return setFormUrl(this)">
  <input type="text" id="lienYoutube">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
```

but here the returned empty value.

how can I do it please?

Comment: I see you have **getValue** function, but call **vgetValue** function. It's a normal?

Comment: @mr_alex Oh yes, I did not pay attention, thank you but it still does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a name in your input. HTML forms, use the `name` attribute to pass values.

You do not even need to set the `action` attribute with JS.
So simply, add your `videoYoutube.asp` in the `action` attribute and add a `name` attribute in the corresponding input, as follows.

```
<form id="testForm" method="get" action="videoYoutube.asp">
    <input type="text" id="lienYoutube" name="lienYout">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: It's correct! But onsubmit="setFormUrl(event)" is extra I think

Comment: the name of the input should be **lienYout**

Comment: @D.Khumoyun I have already modified, thank you for your remark